# My componentDidUpdate doesn't know the keyword this

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

Hi I am trying to detect the auth state inside the class component.
The auth state detection function comes from firebase  doc.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          this.setState({
            displayDialog: true,
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            displayDialog: false,
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

My problem is that the key word `this` is giving me this message & i don't know how to bind this to object like normal function,

```
"owner": "typescript",
    "message": "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.",
    "source": "ts",
```

Comment: @GalAbra my code is inside the class component. The question you mention is pure javascipt function. Not working for me. Maybe can you show me the way

Comment: Use an arrow function instead.